# Levelling the bases of Feynman diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am drawing Feynman diagrams using `tikz-feynman`. When I am drawing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{feynds}
\author{ts342139 }
\date{October 2023}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\tikzfeynmanset{plain/.style=}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{0.6}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a1);
    \vertex[right= of a1] (a2);
    \vertex[above right=  of a2](a3);
    \vertex[below right=  of a2](a4);
    \vertex[below right= of a3] (a5);
    \vertex[right= of a5] (d);
    
    \diagram* {
    (a1) -- [plain, edge label=$q$] (a2),
    (a2)-- [plain, quarter left] (a3),
    (a2)--[plain,quarter right] (a4),
    (a3)--[plain, quarter left] (a5),
    (a4)--[plain, quarter right] (a5),
    (a5)--[plain, edge label=$q$] (d),
    (a3)--[plain, very thick] (a4),
    };
        
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\scalebox{0.45}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex (a);
        \vertex[below right=1.0cm of a] (b);
        \vertex[below right=1.3cm of b] (c);
        \vertex[below right=1.3cm of c] (d);
        \vertex[right= 2.0cm of d] (e);
        \vertex[below left=1.3cm of d] (f);
        \vertex[below left=1.3cm of f] (g);
        \vertex[below left=1.0cm of g] (h);
    \diagram*{
    (a)-- [plain, edge label=$p_1$] (b),
    (b)-- [plain] (c),
    (c)-- [plain] (d),
    (d)-- [plain, edge label=$q$] (e),
    (d)--[plain] (f),
    (f)--[plain] (g),
    (g)--[plain, edge label=$p_2$] (h),
    (c)--[plain, very thick] (f),
    (f)--[plain] (b),
    };
        
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

The adjacent diagrams are not in the same level.
[image]

In particular I want the horizontal lines at same level. How to make them at same level?

Comment: Do you run LuaLatex or pdflated? // Can you please add to your code what's missing to copy and compile your example? Thank you

Comment: I am using Pdflatex

Comment: If I remember correctly, the manual gives a different advice. Can you please check? Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO LuaLaTeX is needed for automatic placement. In this case the diagrams should look about the same if compiled with PDFLaTeX.

Comment: You mean "level", not "label", right? You want the horizontal lines of the diagrams labelled with *q* to align vertically?

Comment: yes yes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two things you should do:

1. Don't put the `tikzpicture`s inside `\scalebox`es, instead use the `scale` option. For `tikz-feynman` diagrams, you need to use `transform shape` additionally to ensure that scaling works properly. You can un-scale the nodes, to make sure that the font size in both diagrams will be the same. I created a custom `.style` that does this automatically.
2. Use the `baseline` option to refer to the node that you want to set the baseline to for both diagrams. I chose the rightmost coordinate for both diagrams.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\tikzset{
    feynman scale/.style={
        transform shape,
        scale={#1},
        every node/.append style={
            scale={1/#1}
        },
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[feynman scale=0.6, baseline=(d)]
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex (a1);
        \vertex[right=of a1] (a2);
        \vertex[above right=of a2](a3);
        \vertex[below right=of a2](a4);
        \vertex[below right=of a3] (a5);
        \vertex[right=of a5] (d);
        \diagram* {
            (a1) -- [plain, edge label=$q$] (a2),
            (a2) -- [plain, quarter left] (a3),
            (a2) -- [plain, quarter right] (a4),
            (a3) -- [plain, quarter left] (a5),
            (a4) -- [plain, quarter right] (a5),
            (a5) -- [plain, edge label=$q$] (d),
            (a3) -- [plain, very thick] (a4),
        };
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[feynman scale=0.45, baseline=(e)]
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex (a);
        \vertex[below right=1.0cm of a] (b);
        \vertex[below right=1.3cm of b] (c);
        \vertex[below right=1.3cm of c] (d);
        \vertex[right=2.0cm of d] (e);
        \vertex[below left=1.3cm of d] (f);
        \vertex[below left=1.3cm of f] (g);
        \vertex[below left=1.0cm of g] (h);
        \diagram*{
            (a) -- [plain, edge label=$p_1$] (b),
            (b) -- [plain] (c),
            (c) -- [plain] (d),
            (d) -- [plain, edge label=$q$] (e),
            (d) --[plain] (f),
            (f) --[plain] (g),
            (g) --[plain, edge label=$p_2$] (h),
            (c) --[plain, very thick] (f),
            (f) --[plain] (b),
        };
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you check ```scale``` command is not working

Comment: @TanmoyPati Thank you for pointing this out. It seems that the algorithm does not quite adhere to scaling. But there is a workaround. See my edit.